# Problemas al realizar una consulta ala hora de mostrar los datos laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

el problema que tengo es que quiero mostrar los datos con un input tipo text el problema que solo los puedo mostrar con input tipo select y en vez de get() tengo que utilizar el pluck() y solo puedo hacer la consulta para una sola tabla y un solo campo y yo quiero hacer una sola consulta para varias pero ala hora de mostrar los datos con el tipo get() y lo recorro me tira un error  los datos si me los trae pero el problema ala hora de mostrarlos

```
$nivel_academico=\DB::table('empleado')
    ->join('nivel_academico','nivel_academico.id','=','empleado.nivel_academico')
    ->join('titulos','titulos.id','=','empleado.titulo_obtenido')
    ->select('nivel_academico.nombre as nivel_academ','nivel_academico.id','titulos.nombre')->where('empleado.id','=',$id) ->get();

//
//    ->pluck('nivel_academ','id');


//          dd($nivel_academico);
        return \View::make('empleado_consultar',compact('pais'))->with([
            'empleado'=>  $empleado,

            'nivel_academico'=>  $nivel_academico,

        ]);

    }
```

aqui muestro uno de los datos que quiero en ese campo

```
    <div class="form-group">
       {!! Form::label('academico', 'Nivel academico:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2      control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-lg-10">

   {{Form::select('nivel_academico',$nivel_academico->nivel_academ,null,['required'=>'required'])}}
          </div>
          </div>
         <br><br><br>
```

este es el error que me tira siempre que lo realizo de esta forma

```
Property [nivel_academ] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ICF\resources\views\empleado_consultar.blade.php)
```

esta es la forma en que si me funciona el problema que no quiero realizar una consulta por cada campo creo que lo mas razonable seria realizar una sola consulta

```
$nivel_academico=\DB::table('empleado')
    ->join('nivel_academico','nivel_academico.id','=','empleado.nivel_academico')
    ->select('nivel_academico.nombre as nivel_academ','nivel_academico.id','titulos.nombre')->where('empleado.id','=',$id)
    ->pluck('nivel_academ','id');




//          dd($nivel_academico);
        return \View::make('empleado_consultar',compact('pais','nivel_academico'))->with([
            'empleado'=>  $empleado,
        ]);

    }
```

```
    <div class="form-group">
     {!! Form::label('academico', 'Nivel academico:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
   <div class="col-lg-10">
                                {{Form::select('nivel_academico',$nivel_academico,null,['required'=>'required'])}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br><br><br>
```

Comment: estas seguro que el empleado con el id `$id` tiene asociado un nivel academico?

Comment: si tine un nivel academico esas 2 tablas estan relacionadas

Comment: lo se, lo que pregunte es si justo ese empleado tiene asociado un nivel academico. probaste hacer esto `$nivel_academico['nivel_academ']` a ver si funciona? quiza podrias poner cual es el resultado de ese query que haces

Comment: me tira que las variable nivel_academ esta indefinida

Comment: que te devuelve `dd($nivel_academico);`